# Workflows are not visible at Sharepoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I just get back from vocation and wanted to start working but when I opened my Site with SP Designer 2007 I could not see the Workflows library. My collegues are able to see them.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue. Someone may have removed / modified your permissions on the Site or actually on the workflows folder.

Comment: Please remember to vote if this was helpful to you or not. Thanks.